# PyQt объяснение выполнения конструктора

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyqt6

Проясните, пожалуйста, процесс выполнения конструктора класса, и почему без базового конструктора внутри код не будет выполняться?

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Привет, мир!")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.Alignment.AlignHCenter)
        self.btnQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Закрыть окно")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnQuit)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)
```

Так как я до конца не понимаю роли конструктора:

```
QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
```

Я решаю удалить его. В таком случае выполнение:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('ООП-стиль создания окна')
    window.resize(300, 700)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Выдаст ошибку:

> RuntimeError: super-class `__init__()` of type MyWindow was never called.

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните , что вам нужно пояснить и приведите код, который не будет выполняться без базового конструктора.

Comment: Это не правильно. когда вы что-то не понимая удаляете его. Прочитайте например https://younglinux.info/oopython/init , а потом еще раз уточните что вы не понимаете.

Comment: + https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаете класс, у вас есть возможность наследовать от другого объекта,
в данном случае от `QWidget`, это главное окно вашего приложения.
Однако недостаточно просто унаследовать его, вам нужно вызвать конструктор,
чтобы он правильно инициализировался, и вы можете сделать это с помощью `super`.

С помощью `super` вы можете выбрать запуск метода из объекта вашего класса,
от которого он унаследован.
Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
```

или так:

```
super().__init__()
```

---

---

```
import sys 
#from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                            # PyQt6                              
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                             # PyQt5


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
#    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    def __init__(self):                                                # !!!
        super().__init__()                                             # !!!

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("<h2>Привет, мир!</h2>")
#        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.Alignment.AlignHCenter)     # PyQt6  
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)                 # PyQt5
        
        self.btnQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Закрыть окно")
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)
        
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnQuit)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.resize(400, 150)
    w.setWindowTitle("Привет, мир!")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]